# Passing handle to C++ classes across a C API boundary

Tags: c++, c, api, smart-pointers

I am writing a library in C++, but want it to have a C API, which should also be thread safe. One thing that the API needs to do is to pass back and forth handles (e.g. a structure containing a reference or pointer) of objects created within the library. These objects need to be destroyed at some point, so any handles to such an object that were still in existence would them become invalid.

EDIT: We cannot assume that each handle is only used within a single client thread. In particular I want to handle the case where there are two client threads accessing the same resource simultaneously, one trying to destroy it while the other tries to modify it

There are two paradigms for dealing with this. One is the smart pointer paradigm, for example boost::shared_ptr or std::shared_ptr, which make sure the object is only destroyed when there are no more references to it. However, as I understand it, such pointers aren't possible to implement in C (as it doesn't support constructors and destructors), so this approach won't work in my case. I don't want to rely on the user to call a "release" function for every instance of a handle they obtain, since they inevitably won't.

Another paradigm is to simply destroy the object within the library, and have any subsequent function calls which pass a handle to that object as an input simply return an error code. My question is what techniques or libraries are available to implement this approach, specifically in a multi-threaded application?

EDIT:
The library should of course handle all the allocation of deallocation of internal memory itself. Smart pointers may be also used within the library; they may not be passed across the API, however.

EDIT:
More detail on handles might be used on the client side: the client might have two threads, one of which creates an object. That thread might pass the handle to the second thread, or the second thread might get it from the library using a "find_object" function. The second thread might then continuously update the object, but while that is going on the first thread might destroy the object, making all handles to the object invalid.

I appreciate rough suggestions of an approach - I have come up with some of these myself too. However, the nitty gritty details of things like how a C++ class instance is retrieved and locked, given a handle, while other threads may be attempting to destroy that object, are non-trivial, so I'm really after answers like "I have done the following and it works without fail." or, even better, "This library implements what you're after sensibly and safely".

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/cpp-objs-passed-to-c.html

Comment: @neagoegab: Don't touch that stuff. It's bad for you.

Comment: "...as I understand it, such pointers aren't possible to implement in C (as it doesn't support constructors and destructors), so this approach won't work in my case.",  I just posted an answer that will work in C++ and C.  The destructor is implemented as a callback function.

Comment: @Jonathan: I'd seen that first and disagree. My question focuses specifically on passing handles back of objects which may be destroyed behind your back.

Comment: I've removed the possible duplicate entry since you disagree with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO handles (e.g. simple integer numbers) that are kept as key values in a map of smart pointers internally might be a viable solution.

Though you'll need to have a mechanism that guarantees a handle that was freed by a particular client won't destroy the map entry, as long the handle is still used by other clients in a multithreaded environment.

**UPDATE:**
At least @user1610015 answer isn't such a bad idea (if you're working with a COM enabled environment). In any case you'll need to keep track with some reference counting of your internally managed class instances.

I'm not so experienced with the C++11 or boosts smart pointer features, and how it's possible to intercept or override reference counting mechanism with these. But e.g. [Alexandrescou's loki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_%28C++%29) library [smart pointer](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00634.html) considerations may let you implement an appropriate policy on how you're going to handle the reference counting and which interfaces can access this or not.

It should be possible with Alexandrescou's [Smart Pointer](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25264) to provide a ref counting mechanism that supports access via a C-API and C++ internal implementation concurrently and thread safe.

Comment: I like the map of smart pointers idea. Is getting a copy of a shared_ptr, e.g. a weak_ptr, from the map thread safe?

Comment: @user664303 Good question! As I mentioned meanwhile, I'm not so experienced with the std C++11 or boost smart pointers. But I've been working with the loki policy based design, which turned out to be very powerful for special cases, or environment specific ports. It's not very practical by means of having so much template parameters (policies) for the standard use cases, but whenever you have deviations, wow! There's also a sample, how to work with COM reference counted pointers. All *you* need to provide in the end, is thread safe reference counting for a particular pointee (instance).

Comment: I asked the next part here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065543/atomically-accessing-resources-stored-in-a-map

Comment: @user664303 OK, I've had a look at your next question. My idea (vs. securing the map access with a separate synch object like a mutex) using the loki smart pointer was to introduce a new policy implementation, which will handle the ref-counting and the bookkeeping of the map entries in one go (and secured with the same synch object). When you're going to delete the pointee of the smart pointer (as ref-count goes to zero), you could also delete the map entry. This of course requires a special smart pointer implementation that is supposed to live in this map and knows about its instance.

Comment: @user664303 ... continuation: Additionally you'll need to increment ref count explicitly whenever you're delivering a handle for an existing instance to your (C-API) client's. Same applies for decrementing ref count with a C-API declared 'dispose' or 'destroy' method.

Answer (score 2):

When code uses handles, it is almost always responsible for calling a dispose handle function.  And operating on a disposed handle is then illegal.

Handles are usually either pointers to forward decl `struct` with no body, or pointers to `struct`with a preable field or two (maybe to help debugging on the C side) that are incomplete.  Creation and destruction of them occur inside the API.

In the API you have a full view ofthe contents of the handle, which need not be a C struct -- it can have unique ptrs or whatever.  You will have to delete the handle manually, but that is inevidable.

As noted below, another possible handle is a `guid`, with inside the API having a map from guid to data.  This is slow, but the space of guids is practically infinite, so you can detect use of `erased` handles and return an error.  Note that failure to return a handle leaks the resource, but this eliminates dangling pointer segfaults at a modsst runtime cost.

Comment: Yes, there is a delete object function. However, there is no reference counting (because that relies on the client calling a release function for every handle that it gets, which is a constraint I don't want to impose on the user, who will generally not be a particularly able programmer), so I need to deal with the case that two handles to the same object exist in different threads on the client side, and one of them is used to delete the object. What then happens when using the other handle?

Comment: You crash?  You sometimes notice and crash cleanly informing the programmer that they made an error?  C code require manually freeing every resource you own.  If you have a C api, either users of the api must perfectly manage resources manually, or you have resource leaks.  Period.  Why are you giving non able programmers a C api?

Comment: Ie, a chreap leak would be to allocate guids for each handle, and dangling resources are just unrecognized guids.  Running out of guids is unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

> One thing that the API needs to do is to pass back and forth handles

Ok so far

> (e.g. a structure containing a reference or pointer)

Why?  A "handle" is just a way to identify an object.  Doesn't necessarily mean it has to hold the reference or pointer.

> One is the smart pointer paradigm, for example boost::shared_ptr or std::shared_ptr, which make sure the object is only destroyed when there are no more references to it.

Sure, a

```
map<int, boost::shared_ptr<my_object>>
```

might work fine here if you want to use it for your memory deallocation mechanism.

> simply destroy the object within the library,

This can exist with smart pointers, its not one or the other.

> have any subsequent function calls which pass a handle to that object as an input simply return an error code.

sure sounds good.

If your library is responsible for allocating memory, then it should be responsible for deallocating memory.

I would return simple integer "handles" from the library _GetNewObject() method.

Your library needs a map of handles to internal objects.  No one outside the library should see the objects from the C interface.

All the library methods should take a handle as their first parameter.

For the multi-threaded stuff, do two threads need to access the same object?  If so, you'll need to put in some sort of locking that occurs when a C API function is entered, and released before it leaves.  You will have to make a decision if you want the code outside the library to know about this locking (you probably don't), a C function that calls the library function will probably just want to get the return value and not worry about the lock/unlock.

So your library needs:

- an interface to allocate and deallocate objects, viewed as handles by the outside
- an interface to do stuff given the handles.

EDIT: MORE INFO

Within the library I would use a Factory pattern to create new objects.  The Factory should hand out a shared_ptr after the object allocation.  This way everything else in the library just uses shared_ptr, and the cleanup will be fairly automatic (i.e. the factory doesn't have to store a list of what is created to remember to clean up, and no one has to call delete explicitly).  Store the shared_ptr in the map with the handle.  You'll probably need some sort of static counter along with a GetNextHandle() function to get the next available handle and to deal with wrap around (depending on how many objects are created and destroyed within the lifetime of the running program).

Next, put your shared pointer into a Proxy.  The proxy should be very lightweight and you can have many Proxy objects per actual object.  Each proxy will hold a private shared_ptr and whatever thread / mutex object you choose to use (you haven't given any information about this, so its hard to be any more specific).  When a Proxy is created, it should acquire the mutex, and release on destruction (i.e. RAII for releasing the lock).

You haven't included any information on how to determine if you want to create a new object or find an existing object, and how two different threads would "find" the same object.  However, lets assume that you have a GetObject() with enough parameters to uniquely identify each object and return the handle from the map, if the objects exists.

In this case, each of your visible extern C library functions would accept an object handle and:

Create a new Proxy for the given handle.  In the Proxy constructor, the Proxy would look in the map to find the handle, if it doesn't exist, ask the Factory to create one (or return an error, your choice here).  The Proxy would then acquire the lock.  Your function would then get the pointer from the Proxy and use it.  When the function exits, the Proxy goes out of scope, releases the lock, and decrements the reference counter.

If two functions are running in different threads, as long as a Proxy exists in one of the functions, the object will still exist.  The other function could ask the library to delete the object which would remove the reference from the map.  Once all the other functions with active Proxy objects finish, the final shared_ptr will go out of scope and the object will be deleted.

You can do most of this generically with templates, or write concrete classes.

EDIT: MORE INFO

The Proxy will be a small class.  It will have a shared_ptr, and have a lock.  You would instantiate a Proxy within the scope of the extern C function called by the client (note, this is actually a C++ function with all the benefits such as being able to use C++ classes).  The proxy is small and should go on the stack (do not new and delete this, more trouble than its worth, just make a scoped variable and let C++ do the work for you).  The proxy would use the RAII pattern to get a copy of the shared_ptr (which would increment the reference count of the shared_ptr) and acquire the lock at construction.  When the Proxy goes out of scope, the shared_ptr it has is destroyed thus decrementing the reference count.  The Proxy destructor should release the lock.  BTW, you may want to think about blocking and how you want your thread mutexes to work. I don't know enough about your specific mutex implementation to suggest anything yet.

The map will contain the "master" shared_ptr that all others are copied from.  However, this is flexible and decoupled because once a Proxy gets a shared_ptr from the map, it doesn't have to worry about "giving it back".  The shared_ptr in the map can be removed (i.e. the object no longer "exists" to the Factory), but there can still be Proxy classes that have a shared_ptr, so the actual object will still exist as long as something is using it.

Comment: "Doesn't necessarily mean it has to hold the reference or pointer". Agreed. That's why I wrote e.g., meaning "for example", making it clear that there are other approaches.

Comment: "[Destroying the object within the library] can exist with smart pointers, its not one or the other." Again, agreed. But you're not passing the smart pointers through the API, crucially, which is the distinction I was making.

Comment: @user664303, ok, just trying to help.  You can delete the second paragraph then since it doesn't apply to the question.  (I could do this, but it won't work)  Why mention it in the first place?

Comment: @user664303, it seemed like you needed a little help cementing what you already know, so that's what I tried to do.

Comment: Well I certainly appreciate the input, thank you. I am actually after something that is known to work, in particular for certain tricky situations, so I have updated my question to reflect that. Your answer helped me do that, so again, thank you. Of course, you will have noticed that I found some of the phrasing you used annoying, because it implied that I didn't know some things that I knew perfectly well. Hopefully a lesson for future answers. Why give an example? Well, if someone is way off track reading the description, hopefully it will be obvious to them from the example.

Comment: @user664303, no harm no foul.  Without a little context of how the objects are used from the API, it is hard to suggest anything more concrete.  Also needed is clarification on how the threads interact.  Will a thread pass an existing handle to another thread?  Or should two thread somehow decide they both need the same object independently?  Can you add a simple lifecycle description for an object within the library?  I'll update my answer with some design patterns.

Comment: OK, getting somewhere here. Yes, there will be "find" functionality. With you on the static counter. Not sure about the proxy: Does it contain a shared pointer, i.e. does it increment the reference count? If so then I don't see how the reference count is decremented when the handle goes out of scope on the client side, since there will be no destructor. If it's just a reference to the shared_ptr then if the shared_ptr is destroyed, what happens to the lock? Is it destroyed, or do I need a separate pool of locks, which are never destroyed?

Comment: @user664303, see my edit above.  The functionality of the shared_ptr and lock are independent.  You are using composition in the Proxy to associate the two.  The shared_ptr is for memory management only, the lock is for thread control only.

Comment: I don't see a need for a mutex in the proxy - what am I protecting with it, especially if each proxy has its own mutex? The object that the shared_ptr points to has a mutex, which I'll need to acquire if I want to read from & write to the object, but there is only one of those per object. I also need to protect the finding and copying of the shared_ptr from the map. How are you proposing to do that? Currently I'm considering using a single mutex for the entire map.

Comment: @user664303, you want to use RAII (have you googled that term?) to acquire and release.  This is a very common C++ pattern that makes sure things happen (i.e. your lock is released) even in the presence of exceptions.  You can leave the mutex in the object (if you want, I would again use composition here), but acquiring it and releasing it should be in the Proxy (half the reason to have the proxy as an RAII object for getting/releasing reliably).  You shouldn't need to protect finding and copying a shared_ptr (why do you say that?)  You only need to protect operations on the object.

Comment: @user664303, before we go any further, please post relevant code examples of what you have so far, probably in a different post.  Without specifics, it is hard to be specific.  I think I've laid out a the design info in enough general detail.

Comment: You need to protect the "finding and copying" in order to make that process atomic, because std::map access is not threadsafe. Instead I have now implemented a static array (indexed by an integer handle) of object pointers and locks, so the locks are not now part of the dynamically allocated object and are guaranteed to exist. That means I can acquire a lock first and check the handle validity afterwards. I am now using RAII to acquire and release the locks. Let's leave it there. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to expose a COM API. This has the benefit that it's object-oriented, unlike a C API. But it still can be used from C. It would look like this:

C++:

```
// Instantiation:
ISomeObject* pObject;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(..., IID_PPV_ARGS(&pObject));

// Use:
hr = pObject->SomeMethod(...);

// Cleanup:
pObject->Release();
```

C:

```
// Instantiation:
ISomeObject* pObject;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(..., IID_PPV_ARGS(&pObject));

// Use:
hr = (*pObject->lpVtbl->SomeMethod)(pObject, ...);

// Cleanup:
(*pObject->lpVtbl->Release)(pObject);
```

Also, if the client is C++, it can use a COM smart pointer like ATL's CComPtr to automate memory management. So the C++ code could be turned into:

```
// Instantiation:
CComPtr<ISomeObject> pSomeObject;
HRESULT hr = pSomeObject.CoCreateInstance(...);

// Use:
hr = pSomeObject->SomeMethod(...);

// Cleanup is done automatically at the end of the current scope
```

Comment: But this would work with COM enabled environments (e.g. Windows) only, right? The OP didn't mention windows at all ...
One could define such an interface (usable in C), though.

Comment: @user1610015: Thanks. Ideally I'm after something cross-platform, but the approach is interesting. However, I'm particularly after something that doesn't rely on a user calling a release function on a handle before it is freed (which is needed if the client is C), as sloppy use of the library will lead to memory leaks. Imagine I get a handle, then in another thread I destroy the object, while that handle still exists. I need a system that copes with that.

Comment: @user664303 COM objects are actually reference-counted, so a call to IUnknown::Release won't destroy the object if there are still other strong references to the object (which can be acquired by calling IUnknow::AddRef). As for the cross-platform part, there are other implementations of COM, for example Firefox uses XPCOM (Cross-Plaform COM), or you can just implement a very simple COM replacement that just uses vtables.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I have too much time on my hands... but I've thought about this a few times and decided to just go ahead and implement it.  C++ calleable, no external libs.  Totally reinvented the wheel, just for fun (if you can call coding on a sunday fun.)

Note, synchronization is not here, because I don't know what OS you are on...

SmartPointers.h:

```
#ifndef SMARTPOINTER_H
#define SMARTPOINTER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef __cplusplus
#define bool int
#define true (1 == 1)
#define false (1 == 0)
#endif

// Forward declarations  
struct tSmartPtr;
typedef struct tSmartPtr SmartPtr;

struct tSmartPtrRef;
typedef struct tSmartPtrRef SmartPtrRef;

// Type used to describe the object referenced.
typedef void * RefObjectPtr;

// Type used to describe the object that owns a reference.
typedef void * OwnerPtr;

// "Virtual" destructor, called when all references are freed.
typedef void (*ObjectDestructorFunctionPtr)(RefObjectPtr pObjectToDestruct);

// Create a smart pointer to the object pObjectToReference, and pass a destructor that knows how to delete the object.
SmartPtr *SmartPtrCreate( RefObjectPtr pObjectToReference, ObjectDestructorFunctionPtr Destructor );

// Make a new reference to the object, pass in a pointer to the object that will own the reference.  Returns a new object reference.
SmartPtrRef *SmartPtrMakeRef( SmartPtr *pSmartPtr, OwnerPtr pReferenceOwner );

// Remove a reference to an object, pass in a pointer to the object that owns the reference.  If the last reference is removed, the object destructor is called.
bool SmartPtrRemoveRef( SmartPtr *pSmartPtr, OwnerPtr pReferenceOwner );

// Remove a reference via a pointer to the smart reference itself.
// Calls the destructor if all references are removed.
// Does SmartPtrRemoveRef() using internal pointers, so call either this or SmartPtrRemoveRef(), not both.
bool SmartPtrRefRemoveRef( SmartPtrRef *pRef );

// Get the pointer to the object that the SmartPointer points to.
void *SmartPtrRefGetObjectPtr(  SmartPtrRef *pRef );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // #ifndef SMARTPOINTER_H
```

SmartPointers.c:

```
#include "SmartPointers.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct tLinkedListNode {
  struct tLinkedListNode *pNext;
} LinkedListNode;

typedef struct tLinkedList {
  LinkedListNode dummyNode;
} LinkedList;

struct tSmartPtrRef {
  LinkedListNode    listNode;
  OwnerPtr          pReferenceOwner;
  RefObjectPtr      pObjectReferenced;
  struct tSmartPtr *pSmartPtr;
};

struct tSmartPtr {
  OwnerPtr                    pObjectRef;
  ObjectDestructorFunctionPtr ObjectDestructorFnPtr;
  LinkedList refList;
};

// Initialize singly linked list
static void LinkedListInit( LinkedList *pList )
{
  pList->dummyNode.pNext = &pList->dummyNode;
}

// Add a node to the list
static void LinkedListAddNode( LinkedList *pList, LinkedListNode *pNode )
{
  pNode->pNext = pList->dummyNode.pNext;
  pList->dummyNode.pNext = pNode;
}

// Remove a node from the list
static bool LinkedListRemoveNode( LinkedList *pList, LinkedListNode *pNode )
{
  bool removed = false;
  LinkedListNode *pPrev = &pList->dummyNode;
  while (pPrev->pNext != &pList->dummyNode) {
    if  (pPrev->pNext == pNode) {
      pPrev->pNext = pNode->pNext;
      removed = true;
      break;
    }
    pPrev = pPrev->pNext;
  }
  return removed;
}

// Return true if list is empty.
static bool LinkedListIsEmpty( LinkedList *pList )
{
  return (pList->dummyNode.pNext == &pList->dummyNode);
}

// Find a reference by pReferenceOwner
static SmartPtrRef * SmartPtrFindRef( SmartPtr *pSmartPtr, OwnerPtr pReferenceOwner )
{
  SmartPtrRef *pFoundNode = NULL;
  LinkedList * const pList = &pSmartPtr->refList;
  LinkedListNode *pIter = pList->dummyNode.pNext;
  while ((pIter != &pList->dummyNode) && (NULL == pFoundNode)) {
    SmartPtrRef *pCmpNode = (SmartPtrRef *)pIter;
    if  (pCmpNode->pReferenceOwner == pReferenceOwner) {
      pFoundNode = pCmpNode;
    }
    pIter = pIter->pNext;
  }
  return pFoundNode;
}

// Commented in header.
SmartPtrRef *SmartPtrMakeRef( SmartPtr *pSmartPtr, OwnerPtr pReferenceOwner )
{
  // TODO: Synchronization here!
  SmartPtrRef *pRef = (SmartPtrRef *)malloc(sizeof(SmartPtrRef) );
  LinkedListAddNode( &pSmartPtr->refList, &pRef->listNode );
  pRef->pReferenceOwner = pReferenceOwner;
  pRef->pObjectReferenced = pSmartPtr->pObjectRef;
  pRef->pSmartPtr = pSmartPtr;
  return pRef;
}

// Commented in header.
bool SmartPtrRemoveRef( SmartPtr *pSmartPtr, OwnerPtr pReferenceOwner )
{
  // TODO: Synchronization here!
  SmartPtrRef *pRef = SmartPtrFindRef( pSmartPtr, pReferenceOwner ); 
  if (NULL != pRef) {
    assert( LinkedListRemoveNode( &pSmartPtr->refList, &pRef->listNode ) );
    pRef->pReferenceOwner = NULL;
    pRef->pObjectReferenced = NULL;
    free( pRef );
    if (LinkedListIsEmpty( &pSmartPtr->refList ) ) {
      pSmartPtr->ObjectDestructorFnPtr( pSmartPtr->pObjectRef );
    }
  }
  return (NULL != pRef);
}

// Commented in header.
bool SmartPtrRefRemoveRef( SmartPtrRef *pRef )
{
  return SmartPtrRemoveRef( pRef->pSmartPtr, pRef->pReferenceOwner );
}

// Commented in header.
void *SmartPtrRefGetObjectPtr(  SmartPtrRef *pRef )
{
  return pRef->pObjectReferenced;
}

// Commented in header.
SmartPtr *SmartPtrCreate( void *pObjectToReference, ObjectDestructorFunctionPtr Destructor )
{
  SmartPtr *pThis = (SmartPtr *)malloc( sizeof( SmartPtr ) );
  memset( pThis, 0, sizeof( SmartPtr ) );
  LinkedListInit( &pThis->refList );
  pThis->ObjectDestructorFnPtr = Destructor;
  pThis->pObjectRef = pObjectToReference;
  return pThis;
}
```

And a test program (main.cpp)

```
// SmartPtrs.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SmartPointers.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct tMyRefObj {
  int       refs;
  SmartPtr *pPointerToMe;
  bool      deleted;
} MyRefObj;

static bool objDestructed = false;

static MyRefObj *MyObjectGetReference( MyRefObj *pThis, void *pObjectReferencing )
{
  // TODO: Synchronization here...
  pThis->refs++;
  SmartPtrRef * const pRef = SmartPtrMakeRef( pThis->pPointerToMe, pObjectReferencing );
  return (MyRefObj *)SmartPtrRefGetObjectPtr( pRef );
}

static void MyObjectRemoveReference( MyRefObj *pThis, void *pObjectReferencing )
{
  // TODO: Synchronization here...
  pThis->refs--;
  assert( SmartPtrRemoveRef( pThis->pPointerToMe, pObjectReferencing ) );
}

static void MyObjectDestructorFunction(void *pObjectToDestruct)
{
  MyRefObj *pThis = (MyRefObj *)pObjectToDestruct;
  assert( pThis->refs == 0 );
  free( pThis );
  objDestructed = true;
}

static MyRefObj *MyObjectConstructor( void )
{
    MyRefObj *pMyRefObj =new MyRefObj;
  memset( pMyRefObj, 0, sizeof( MyRefObj ) );
  pMyRefObj->pPointerToMe = SmartPtrCreate( pMyRefObj, MyObjectDestructorFunction );
  return pMyRefObj;
}

#define ARRSIZE 125
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i;
  // Array of references
  MyRefObj *refArray[ARRSIZE];

  // Create an object to take references of.
  MyRefObj *pNewObj = MyObjectConstructor();

  // Create a bunch of references.
  for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++) {
    refArray[i] = MyObjectGetReference( pNewObj, &refArray[i] );
  }

  assert( pNewObj->refs == ARRSIZE );

  for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++) {
    MyObjectRemoveReference( pNewObj, &refArray[i] );
    refArray[i] = NULL;
  }
  assert(objDestructed);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! That is impressive. Thank you for going to the trouble. But what if I store a reference in a local variable on the client side, then exit the scope without removing it? How is that handled?

Comment: You can create a little helper c++ class that knows about the smart pointers c implementation and can allocate a new one in the constructor and remove it in the destructor. Then use the c++ class from c++ code, and construction and destruction will happen automagically when you declare the local / leave the context.