# Atomically accessing resources stored in a map

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, stdmap

I want to store some std::shared_ptr to C++ class instances in a map, e.g. a std::map, using an integer key. However, I need this map to have two properties:

1. If the key doesn't exist, then return an error rather than create a new object.
2. If the key does exist then grab a copy of the std::shared_ptr atomically. I.e. it should not be possible to delete an object from the map in one thread while simultaneously retrieving it from the map in another.

I'd like to avoid having a single mutex (even multiple read, single write) for getting and removing objects from the map if possible, to avoid the overhead.

Does such a map class exist in any library? If not, can you suggest how to implement one?

Comment: see the notes on the answer I gave at your 1st question here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053173/passing-handle-to-c-classes-across-a-c-api-boundary/15053247#15053247)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elements inside the collection have mutexes you can simply use lock-free data structures. There are implemented in C++ in [boost 1.53.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lockfree.html).

However I would advice to look at mutexes once again - in many cases they will offer better performance the lock-free data structure (although not always) and are much easier to manage. As long as there is no loop of mutexes you should be fine.

As of access-without-creation use [std::map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) if you use C++03 (returns iterator) or [std::map::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) if you use C++11 (returns reference).

**EDIT**: Actually [std::map::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) is possibly worse unless you assume that the normal case is that element is present (i.e. against rule to use exceptions only for exceptional state instead of normal operation). However it probably depends also on philosophy one applies to exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly there could well be a loop of mutexes. I didn't see a suitable lock-free data structure here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lockfree.html. Any hints?

Comment: Actually, there shouldn't be a loop of mutexes because all I'm doing is copying a shared_ptr. The lock of the object is then only grabbed after the map access mutex is released. Thanks!

Comment: @user664303: Please note that you need to do: 1. lock set mutex 2. find and copy a `std::shared_ptr` 3. unlock mutex. If copy is outside mutex it might get deleted from map and it be last reference (deleting the object).

Answer (score 2):

1) Use [std::map::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at). That will raise an exception if the key is not present

2) Use an active object to access the map. The active object takes care of serializing operations and thus avoiding race conditions, yet allows you to use a plain old `std::map`.

Comment: @user664303 There are some good links [here](http://herbsutter.com/2010/07/12/effective-concurrency-prefer-using-active-objects-instead-of-naked-threads/). This is a great series about concurrency in modern C++. One of the videos, I think [this one](http://herbsutter.com/2013/01/15/videos-panel-and-c-concurrency/) might have a sample implementation in C++11.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will watch the video. However, in this application it's not clear to me if an active object would offer any benefit over a single mutex. Two objects could not be retrieved concurrently, and there would be an overhead.